# understanding backslash in POSIX standard

Tags: bash, shell, posix

I've seen interesting video about POSIX standard on youtube.

It was part of lecture, asking if anyone knows the result of

`echo \\\\\\`

in bash, and sh(POSIX standard?)

```
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\

\\

bash$ echo \\\\\\

\\\
```

I wanted to find the video again, but I just couldn't.

I just can't figure it out how this happened.

Comment: Your two examples are *both* running in Bash, I think - is that what was in the video, or what you've observed yourself? If so, where and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets a bit complicated. There are actually *three* different cases: two POSIX variants, and what Bash does.

First, the shell handles what you wrote. The POSIX shell language, along with Bash, [supports backslash quoting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01), which

> preserves the literal value of the following character

So `\\` represents a single `\` in the argument given to the command.

Your example, `echo \\\\\\`, has three pairs of backslashes. The shell interprets those escapes and gives three backslashes, `\\\`, as the argument to `echo` (equivalent to `echo '\\\'`).

In all cases, the `echo` command gets the same argument, but they interpret it differently.

---

## POSIX

There is an optional POSIX extension ([XSI, or X/Open System Interfaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_01_04)), which is very commonly supported today. It's possible to be POSIX-conformant without supporting XSI, and it makes a difference in this situation.

**With XSI**, [`echo` requires that the backslash escapes are interpreted within arguments](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), including

> ```
> \\
>     Write a <backslash> character.
> ```

**Without XSI**, POSIX instead states that

> If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined.

and so no particular outcome is specified (or, both versions you saw are allowed).

POSIX/XSI `echo` will interpret the first pair of backslashes as an escape itself, resulting in `\\` as the output.

---

## Bash

[Bash's builtin `echo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-echo), on the other hand, does not interpret escape sequences unless you provide the `-e` option to ask for it explicitly.

In [Bash's POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode), which is enabled in various circumstances (including when it is invoked as `sh`), *it still does the same thing* (which is allowed as "implementation-defined" behaviour). If you enable the `xpg_echo` option using `shopt -s xpg_echo`, or your `bash` executable was built with the `--enable-xpg-echo-default` configuration option, you will get the POSIX/XSI behaviour.

GNU coreutils `echo` does the same thing.

---

That means that:

1. Under Bash, only the shell-level interpretation happens, and you get three backslashes outputted.
2. Under a POSIX/XSI environment, the backslashes are interpreted *twice*, and you get two backslashes outputted.
3. Under a pure POSIX environment, the implementation gets to choose a behaviour. Either version of the output you saw is allowed.
4. You can configure Bash to have the XSI behaviour of interpreting escapes automatically with `shopt -s xpg_echo`, but it won't ever be enabled without explicitly asking for it.

Comment: oh god.. I wrote the question few hours ago. And I receive the question like this.
Just brilliant. I'm really shocked. where did you come from?.. thank you very much.

Comment: For an even longer exposition of the problems with `echo`, see the answers at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/5132 . (-: